# listas enlazadas de caracteres en c

Tags: c, lista

Estoy practicando listas enlazadas en c, lo que quiero hacer es guardar elementos de tipo char en los nodos, quiero leer esos elemento 
Esto fue lo que hice, pero no se como leer los elementos a la vez que uso un ciclo for :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define CANT_NODOS 5

typedef struct Nodo{
    char* elemento;
    struct Nodo* siguiente; /*vinculo para unir mas nodos*/
}nodo;

//funcion que genera o crea una lista
nodo* ListaElementos(nodo* Lista){
    Lista = NULL ;
    return Lista;
}

// funcion que agrega nodos a la lista 

nodo* agregarNodo (nodo* Lista, char* elemento){
    nodo* nuevoNodo, *aux;
    nuevoNodo = (nodo*) malloc (sizeof(nodo));
    nuevoNodo -> elemento = elemento;
    nuevoNodo -> siguiente = NULL;
    if(Lista == NULL){
        Lista = nuevoNodo;
    }
    else{
        aux = Lista; //para no perder el elemento
        while(aux->siguiente != NULL){
                aux = aux -> siguiente;             
            }
        aux-> siguiente = nuevoNodo;
    }
    return Lista;
}
//Funcion que libera la memoria
void LiberarLista (nodo* Lista ){   

    free (Lista);
}

nodo* Lista1;
nodo* Lista2;

nodo* nodoListas(nodo*Lista){
    int i;
    char prueba, *elemento;

    printf("Cargar elemento: \n");
    //for (i = 0; i< CANT_NODOS; i++){
        //scanf ("%s", elemento);
        Lista = agregarNodo (Lista, "aqui deberia ir lo leido1");
        Lista = agregarNodo (Lista, "aqui deberia ir lo leido2");
        Lista = agregarNodo (Lista, "aqui deberia ir lo leido3");
        Lista = agregarNodo (Lista, "aqui deberia ir lo leido4");
        Lista = agregarNodo (Lista, "aqui deberia ir lo leido5");
    //}

}

int main(void){
    Lista1 = ListaElementos(Lista1);
    Lista2 = ListaElementos(Lista2);
    Lista1 = nodoListas(Lista1);

//impresion Lista 1
    while (Lista1 != NULL){
        printf("%s\t", Lista1->elemento);
        Lista1 = Lista1 -> siguiente;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

alguna sugerencia? ):

Comment: Me resulta dificil de creer que seas capaz de gestionar listas enlazadas y memoria dinámica y no tengas ni idea sobre cómo usar un `for`. ¿Seguro que ese código es tuyo?

Comment: Tampoco tienes que ser rudo, silo es y no es que no sepa utilizar un for, mi problema mas bien es con la cadena que quiero pasar

Comment: no intento ser rudo, pero la gestion de listas enlazadas es mucho mas compleja que programar un for... eso y que por aquí pasa mucha gente pidiendo que le hagan los deberes